# How to call React Server Actions (in Next.js 14) programmatically to simulate rate limits?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rate-limiting, server-action

I have a `signup` action that takes an `email` as a form input using `FormData` & adds a value to database.

I want to simulate rate limit using just `fetch` api. How can I do that?

I don't want to use playwright or simulate 100s of requests in browser by having another button.

I just want to use `fetch`. Is it technically possible?

I tried with the following code:

```js
async function main() {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('email', 'hey@yo.com')

  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })

  const data = await res.json()

  console.log({ data })
}

main()
```

And typed `tsx ./rate-limit/signup.ts` in the terminal.

But it only gave me the html back.

Curious if its possible at all like `/api` routes?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide the `Next-Action` header:

```js
 const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
        'Next-Action': '0917c6804f07eaf34c42aa6867f90bf00983db90' // <-- Replace with your action id
    }
  })
```

I didn't find out how to get this action id automatically but manually you can obtain it by inspecting the request headers in the network tab of the browser dev tools.

**Edit:** You can find `Next-Action` number by using a library like `cheerio`. I used a faster one. Here's a little script:

```js
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser'

export const LOCALHOST_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

export async function getActionNo(): Promise<string> {
  const res = await fetch(`${LOCALHOST_URL}/signup`)
  const html = await res.text()
  const $ = parse(html)
  const str = $.querySelector('input[name="$ACTION_1:0"]')
    ?.getAttribute('value')
    ?.toString() as string
  const data = JSON.parse(str)

  return data.id // '0917c6804f07eaf34c42aa6867f90bf00983db90'
}
```

Comment: that is quite rad. would've loved a way to automatically get it though. bdw, how do you read the response? i tried `res.json()` but it gave an error: `undefined:1
0:["$@1",["development",null]]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 1`

Comment: and i get `⨯ Error: Connection closed.
    at e.exports.emit (node:events:526:35)` on the server itself. how do i solve for that?

Comment: The id can be found at the RSC payload. You can find it at `.next/server/app/page.rsc` for `app/page.tsx`. and it's injected in the html as `<script>self.__next_f.push([1,"3:I[9070,[],\"\"]\n6:I[2070,[],\"\"]\n7:I[8932,[],\"\"]\n9:I[4357,[],\"\"]\n5:{\"id\":\"5c6b6f7fc68fd1e20049dfd2eabe0f7c2318f6c2\",\"bound\":null}\na:[]\n"])</script>`. If you render a `<form action={signupAction}>` you can easily scrape the first hidden input of the form `<form action="" encType="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="$ACTION_ID_5c6b6f7fc68fd1e20049dfd2eabe0f7c2318f6c2"/></form>`.

Comment: yeah, i thought about scraping as an easy solution but what about the other error? i couldnt get it to send a request that passes through. [this is the project](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-14-lucia-v3-sqlite-drizzle-conform-zod-email-verification-otp-server-actions)

Comment: Server Action response by `text/x-component` not a json.

Comment: i'm not able to make the above answer work. how do i set `text/x-component` or where do i set it?

Comment: maybe its because i'm not returning any response i guess. my actions are returned by conform. see [actions/signup.ts](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-14-lucia-v3-sqlite-drizzle-conform-zod-email-verification-otp-server-actions/blob/main/src/app/actions/signup.ts)